# CSS for DIV tag is working incorrectly

Tags: html, css, master-pages

Somehow the CSS is going awry.

In my CSS class, the `maincontent` section is defined as

### CSS:

```
.page {
  background: #B5AAAA; /* Hoof color */
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
}
.main {
  position: absolute;
  /* I commented this out because it is new to me.
     I was not sure if it was causing my issues or not.
  min-height: 420px;
  min-width: 960px;
  */
  top:150px;
}
.maincontent {
  background-color: #F2E6E6; /* Almost white, just a tad on the maroon side */
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid #4D0000;
  overflow: auto;
  left:110px;
  top:0px;
  height: 500px;
  width:100%;
}
```

Cutting out all of the unrelated parts of my Site.Master's HTML, I have this left:

### Site.Master:

```
<body>
  <form runat="server">
    <asp:scriptmanager runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="main">
        <div class="maincontent">
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Here is the section from the page that inherits it:

### Sales.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="mainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <table border="1" >
  ... // lots of rows and columns
  </table>
  ...
```

So, does anyone understand why I am seeing **102px** for the width of my table below?

I'd like that particular  to fill the rest of the space to the Right.

### Google Chrome "Inspect Element" Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you need to make `.page` `position:relative` and you haven't given main a width so maincontent won't know what to take 100% of

Comment: `width` is set to 100%, thus somewhere it's parent's width is 102px. Or a percentage that equates to 102px

Comment: Man, this forum is GREAT! I knew it had to be something simple, but I didn't know what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the maincontent `div` doesn't have any knowledge of what it should be 100% of, it will be 100% of the size of its nearest `position:relative` (or `absolute`) parent.

So set

```
 .page{
    width:100%;
    position:relative
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Adam! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

When you absolute position something the browser needs to know what to absolutely position it against. If no positining context is created it will simply position it against the body. You need to create a new positioning context for the parent container, in this case "page"

```
.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Edit:

It would be safer to avoid the use of absolute positioning and rely on margins for the layout:

```
.page {
  background: #B5AAAA; /* Hoof color */
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
}
.main {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.maincontent {
   background-color: #F2E6E6; /* Almost white, just a tad on the maroon side */  
   border: 1px solid #4D0000;
   margin-left: 110px;
}
```

Comment: `margin-left` (or the removal of my `position` attribute) seems to have thrown my **DIV** tag way off to the Right see [here](http://www.poolranch.com/Sales.aspx).

Comment: I had to re-apply my position attrib.